# Commonly used indicators for currency pair strength?

Tags: finance, currency, stock-market, trading

I am attempting to write a program in Python that monitors a single currency pair, GPB/NZD to be specific. My main focus will be to run constant calculations every 2 to 3 minutes in order to give feedback to me when certain indicators have been observed in the current stream of data I am processing which will send me an email.

This is purely a solo project I am wanting to develop but I am having trouble finding some good indicators that I could somewhat utilise in giving myself feedback on current market strength. I don't want to use anything that entails pages of algo calculations but I am willing to mimic some currently used indicators that are a simple examples of strong market movement.

tl;dr: Does anyone know technical names of currency pair indicators used to give feedback on market strength between a currency pair that could be calculated by myself using Python?

Comment: "[The term Market Strength is a little ambiguous.](http://www.chart-formations.com/indicators/market-strength.aspx)"

Comment: many thanks for the link!